# How to move paint graphics along slope?

Tags: java, swing

I have a tank game where you rotate via A/D keys and move forward/backward with W/S. The turret follows the mouse cursor on the screen. I am attempting to get shooting to work when I click. I get the initial degree of the turret rotation on click, as well as the point at the end of the turret. I set `isShooting()` to check if I am currently shooting at the given moment, and it is set to `true` on click. I use `shotFired()` also set to true on click, to tell whether there is a shot on the screen.

I want to have the bullet moving along a straight line with a give slope every time I click, from the end of the barrel to off the screen.

Currently the bullet moves in the wrong directions and is influenced by movement of the turret. I have been working to find the issue and cannot find it.

```
public void update() {
    playerTank.setCenterTurret(new Point2D.Double(playerTank.xPos() + 67, playerTank.yPos() + 125));
    playerTank.setEndTurret(new Point2D.Double(playerTank.xPos() + ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getTurretDegree())))) + 63, playerTank.yPos() + ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getTurretDegree())))) - 25));
    playerTank.setCenterBase(new Point2D.Double(playerTank.xPos() + (playerTank_PNG_WIDTH / 2), playerTank.yPos() + (playerTank_PNG_HEIGHT / 2)));

    mouseLoc = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(mouseLoc, this);

    mouseLocX = (int) mouseLoc.getX();
    mouseLocY = (int) mouseLoc.getY();

    mouseDistX = mouseLocX - playerTank.getCenterTurret().getX();
    mouseDistY = mouseLocY - playerTank.getCenterTurret().getY();

    mouseDegree = angleInRelation(mouseLoc, playerTank.getCenterTurret());

    if(moveUp) {
        playerTank.setLocation(playerTank.xPos() + (MOVEMENT_SPEED * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getBaseDegree()))), playerTank.yPos() - MOVEMENT_SPEED * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getBaseDegree())));
    }
    if(moveDown) {
        playerTank.setLocation(playerTank.xPos() - (MOVEMENT_SPEED * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getBaseDegree()))), playerTank.yPos() + MOVEMENT_SPEED * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getBaseDegree())));
    }
    if(rotateLeft && playerTank.xPos() >= 0) {
        playerTank.setBaseDegree(playerTank.getBaseDegree() - 5);
    }
    if(rotateRight && playerTank.xPos() + playerTank.getWidth() <= FRAME_WIDTH) {
        playerTank.setBaseDegree(playerTank.getBaseDegree() + 5);
    }

    mouseDegree -= playerTank.getBaseDegree();

    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setBackground(Color.white);
    g2D.setColor(Color.white);

    g2D.fillRect(0, 0, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

    paintBase(g2D);

    playerTank.setTurretDegree(mouseDegree);
    g2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getTurretDegree()), playerTank.xPos() + 67, playerTank.yPos() + 125);
    paintTurret(g2D);

    paintBullet(g2D);
}

public void paintBullet(Graphics2D g2D) {
    g2D.setColor(Color.black);

    if(playerTank.isShooting()) {
        playerTank.setBulletPos(playerTank.getEndTurret());
        g2D.fillRect((int) playerTank.getEndTurret().getX(), (int) playerTank.getEndTurret().getY(), 8, 18);
        playerTank.setShooting(false);
    }
    if (playerTank.shotFired()) {
        double newX = (BULLET_SPEED * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getInitialTurretDegree()))));
        double newY = (BULLET_SPEED * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(playerTank.getInitialTurretDegree()))));
        playerTank.setBulletPos(playerTank.getBulletX() + newX, playerTank.getBulletY() - newY);
        g2D.fillRect((int) playerTank.getBulletX(), (int) playerTank.getBulletY(), 8, 18);

        if((playerTank.getBulletX() > FRAME_WIDTH || playerTank.getBulletY() > FRAME_HEIGHT) || (playerTank.getBulletX() < 0 || playerTank.getBulletY() < 0)) {
            playerTank.setShotFired(false);
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();` <- Nope, use a `MouseListener`

Comment: A lot of what you're describing is "basic" trigonometry (I say basic, but I'm an idiot, so it's all just a confusing mess for me )

Comment: Usually you override method `paintComponent` and not `paint`. Refer to [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson in _Creating a GUI With Swing_ trail of Oracle's Java tutorials. Also, I think that people who are not using IntelliJ as their IDE (like me) won't be able to help you because of the `MainMenu.form` file.

Comment: *"The GitHub is linked here:"* No thanks. All relevant code should be included in the question in the form of a [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your problem basically boils down to a series of trigonometry problems ... yea (can you feel the sarcasm ).

But what do I mean?  So, you want to find the end point of the barrel, based on it's current angle of rotation?  Well, you will need to know the length of barrel, this will give you a radius around which the barrel can travel, from that you can simply perform a "point on a circle" calculation.

Want to know the path of the projectile, calculate the "point on a circle" based on a radius greater than the visible area and then draw a line between the barrel and this point, that's your path.  Told you, trigonometry.

So, I started by creating a simple entity which would end up looking something like (with color guides)...

[image]

The turret and the body are seperate images, but when drawn on top of each other, they will appear as above, this is really important, as this saves so much effort.

The turret then has a specified radius and can rotate easily around the body

[image]

If you look really hard, the turret is actually not centered around the "natural" center of the image, but by laying it out this way, we can easily rotate around the mid point of the image - so much easier.

Okay, that all sounds fun, let's start with a basic concept of our "tank" entity...

```
public class Tank {
    private BufferedImage body;
    private BufferedImage turret;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private double bodyAngle = 0;
    private double turretAngle = 0;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private int midX;
    private int midY;

    public Tank() throws IOException {
        body = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/TankBody.png"));
        turret = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/TankTurret.png"));

        width = body.getWidth();
        height = body.getHeight();

        midX = width / 2;
        midY = height / 2;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getBodyAngle() {
        return bodyAngle;
    }

    public double getTurretAngle() {
        return turretAngle;
    }

    public void setBodyAngle(double bodyAngle) {
        this.bodyAngle = bodyAngle;
    }

    public void setTurretAngle(double turretAngle) {
        this.turretAngle = turretAngle;
    }

    // This represents the "unrotated" width
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    // This represents the "unrotated" height
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    protected int getMidX() {
        return midX;
    }

    protected int getMidY() {
        return midY;
    }

    protected BufferedImage getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    protected BufferedImage getTurret() {
        return turret;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D master, ImageObserver observer) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) master.create();
        g2d.translate(getX() - getMidX(), getY() - getMidY());

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        Graphics2D bodyG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        bodyG.rotate(Math.toRadians(getBodyAngle()), getMidX(), getMidY());
        // >>> Debug
        bodyG.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker());
        bodyG.drawRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
        // <<< Debug
        bodyG.drawImage(getBody(), 0, 0, observer);
        bodyG.dispose();

        Graphics2D turrtG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        turrtG.rotate(Math.toRadians(getTurretAngle()), getMidX(), getMidY());
        // >>> Debug
        turrtG.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
        // I mesured the turrent size in a image editor
        // The acutal image size is the same as the body
        // in order to make the workflow simpler
        turrtG.drawRect((getWidth() - 20) / 2, 0, 20, 44);
        // <<< Debug
        turrtG.drawImage(getTurret(), 0, 0, observer);
        turrtG.dispose();

        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

The important things to note here are...

- The x/y position of the tank represents it's "center" point
- The body and turret can rotate independently of each other

Now, we can make the turret look at the mouse by using a `MouseMotionListener` and, you guessed it, some more trigonometry

[image]

```
public class GamePane extends JPanel {

    private Tank tank;
    private Point mousePoint;

    public GamePane() throws IOException {
        tank = new Tank();
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                mousePoint = e.getPoint();
            }
        });
        tank.setX(200);
        tank.setY(200);

        Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (mousePoint != null) {
                    double deltaX = tank.getX() - mousePoint.x;
                    double deltaY = tank.getY() - mousePoint.y;
                    // Because the image is pointing up, we need to offset
                    // the rotation by 90 for the API
                    double rotation = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) - Math.toRadians(90));
                    tank.setTurretAngle(rotation);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        tank.paint(g2d, this);
        // I don't trust the tanks paint process ;)
        g2d.dispose();
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // This is all debug
        if (mousePoint != null) {
            // The radius around the tank based on the mouse's current location
            double radius = Point2D.distance(tank.getX(), tank.getY(), mousePoint.x, mousePoint.y);
            g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
                    tank.getX() - radius,
                    tank.getY() - radius,
                    radius * 2,
                    radius * 2));
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

The "core" functionality is in the `Timer` and looks like...

```
double deltaX = tank.getX() - mousePoint.x;
double deltaY = tank.getY() - mousePoint.y;
// Because the image is pointing up, we need to offset
// the rotation by 90 for the API
double rotation = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) - Math.toRadians(90));
```

It's important to note that the `Graphics` API and `Math` API have a different concept of `0` (yea).

Okay, but how do we find the projectile path?!  Well, more trigonometry!

But first, we need some help...

```
public class Util {
    public static Point2D getPointOnCircle(double degress, double offset, double radius) {
        double rads = Math.toRadians(degress + offset); // 0 becomes the top

        // Calculate the outter point of the line
        double xPosy = Math.cos(rads) * radius;
        double yPosy = Math.sin(rads) * radius;

        return new Point2D.Double(xPosy, yPosy);
    }

    public static Point2D getPointOnCircle(double degress, double offset, double radius, double centerX, double centerY) {
        Point2D poc = getPointOnCircle(degress, offset, radius);
        return new Point2D.Double(poc.getX() + centerX, poc.getY() + centerY);
    }
}
```

So, all this does is provide some basic "point on circle" calculations.  From this, we can calculate the "point" in the "world" we're looking for...

So, we can add...

```
public Point2D getBusinessEndOfBarrel() {
    // I've deliberatly set up the images to be the same size, so this
    // can be made easier.  If your turren is a different size/position
    // then you will need calculate this yourself

    // Also, we're calculating this in "world" space
    int centerX = getX();
    int centerY = getY();
    return Util.getPointOnCircle(getTurretAngle(), -90, Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2, centerX, centerY);
}
```

to our `Tank` entity, this will return the "world" coordinates that represents the end of the barrel.

Let's add some "debug" graphics to our `paintComponent`...

```
// This is all debug
if (mousePoint != null) {
    // The radius around the tank based on the mouse's current location
    double radius = Point2D.distance(tank.getX(), tank.getY(), mousePoint.x, mousePoint.y);
    g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
            tank.getX() - radius,
            tank.getY() - radius,
            radius * 2,
            radius * 2));

    // From point, base the turrets current angle
    Point2D fromPoint = tank.getBusinessEndOfBarrel();

    // Mid point of the tank in the world
    int worldMidX = tank.getX();
    int worldMidY = tank.getY();
    // The point on the circle where the mouse is, based on the turrents current angle
    // which the diection the turret is pointing
    Point2D toPoint = Util.getPointOnCircle(tank.getTurretAngle(), -90, radius, worldMidX, worldMidY);

    // The "out of view" radius, this represents the "end point" for our projectile, because, it's easier 
    // to calculate
    double outOfViewRadius = Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 2d;
    Point2D outOfViewToPoint = Util.getPointOnCircle(tank.getTurretAngle(), -90, outOfViewRadius, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    // The projectiles path
    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(fromPoint, outOfViewToPoint));

    // A line from the barrel to the mouse point
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(fromPoint, toPoint));
}
```

This will add...

- A guide which represents the target circle created by the mouse
- A projectile line from the barrel to the mouse
- A projectile line from the barrel to outside the visible area

[image]

You might be surprised that this actually now provides the answer to the question.  You have the start point and end point of the projectile, now you just need some way to animate it...

When it comes to animation, I tend to prefer time based animations, but since the projectile might travel a variable distance, what we really need is a linear progression, so if it was to travel a long distance or a short distance, it would travel at the same speed.

Now, I banged by head against Google for a bit and was able to come up with...

```
public class Projectile {
    private Point2D from;
    private Point2D to;

    private Point2D current;
    
    private long lastUpdate = 0;
    
    private double deltaX;
    private double deltaY;

    public Projectile(Point2D from, Point2D to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        current = new Point2D.Double(from.getX(), from.getY());

        double deltaX = from.getX() - to.getX();
        double deltaY = from.getY() - to.getY();
        double angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) + Math.toRadians(180);
        
        this.deltaY = Math.sin(angle) * 100;
        this.deltaX = Math.cos(angle) * 100;
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public Point2D getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public Point2D getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public Point2D getLocation() {
        return current;
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate;
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        double x = current.getX();
        double y = current.getY();
        
        x += deltaX * (elapsedTime / 1000d);
        y += deltaY * (elapsedTime / 1000d);
        
        current.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

This will basically calculate a x/y delta which needs to be applied to move the projectile from the current point to it's target point using a constant speed.

Now we can add a `MouseListener`...

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int worldMidX = tank.getX();
        int worldMidY = tank.getY();
        Point2D fromPoint = tank.getBusinessEndOfBarrel();
        double outOfViewRadius = Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 2d;
        Point2D toPoint = Util.getPointOnCircle(tank.getTurretAngle(), -90, outOfViewRadius, worldMidX, worldMidY);

        Projectile projectile = new Projectile(fromPoint, toPoint);
        projectiles.add(projectile);
    }
});
```

Update the projectiles in our main loop...

```
List<Projectile> outOfScopeProjectiles = new ArrayList<>(8);
Rectangle visibleBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
for (Projectile projectile : projectiles) {
    projectile.tick();
    Point2D current = projectile.getLocation();
    if (!visibleBounds.contains(current)) {
        outOfScopeProjectiles.add(projectile);
    }
}
projectiles.removeAll(outOfScopeProjectiles);
```

And update our `paintComponent`...

```
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
for (Projectile projectile : projectiles) {
    Point2D current = projectile.getLocation();
    g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(current.getX() - 2, current.getY() - 2, 4, 4));
    // >>> DEBUG
    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(projectile.getFrom(), projectile.getTo()));
    // << DEBUG
}
```

[image]

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new GamePane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        private Tank tank;
        private Point mousePoint;

        private List<Projectile> projectiles = new ArrayList<>(8);

        public GamePane() throws IOException {
            tank = new Tank();
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    mousePoint = e.getPoint();
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    int worldMidX = tank.getX();
                    int worldMidY = tank.getY();
                    Point2D fromPoint = tank.getBusinessEndOfBarrel();
                    double outOfViewRadius = Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 2d;
                    Point2D toPoint = Util.getPointOnCircle(tank.getTurretAngle(), -90, outOfViewRadius, worldMidX, worldMidY);

                    Projectile projectile = new Projectile(fromPoint, toPoint);
                    projectiles.add(projectile);
                }
            });
            tank.setX(200);
            tank.setY(200);

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (mousePoint != null) {
                        double deltaX = tank.getX() - mousePoint.x;
                        double deltaY = tank.getY() - mousePoint.y;
                        // Because the image is pointing up, we need to offset
                        // the rotation by 90 for the API
                        double rotation = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) - Math.toRadians(90));
                        tank.setTurretAngle(rotation);
                    }

                    List<Projectile> outOfScopeProjectiles = new ArrayList<>(8);
                    Rectangle visibleBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                    for (Projectile projectile : projectiles) {
                        projectile.tick();
                        Point2D current = projectile.getLocation();
                        if (!visibleBounds.contains(current)) {
                            outOfScopeProjectiles.add(projectile);
                        }
                    }
                    projectiles.removeAll(outOfScopeProjectiles);

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            tank.paint(g2d, this);
            // I don't trust the tanks paint process ;)
            g2d.dispose();
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            // This is all debug
            if (mousePoint != null) {
                // The radius around the tank based on the mouse's current location
                double radius = Point2D.distance(tank.getX(), tank.getY(), mousePoint.x, mousePoint.y);
                g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
                        tank.getX() - radius,
                        tank.getY() - radius,
                        radius * 2,
                        radius * 2));

                // From point, base the turrets current angle
                Point2D fromPoint = tank.getBusinessEndOfBarrel();

                // Mid point of the tank in the world
                int worldMidX = tank.getX();
                int worldMidY = tank.getY();
                // The point on the circle where the mouse is, based on the turrents current angle
                // which the diection the turret is pointing
                Point2D toPoint = Util.getPointOnCircle(tank.getTurretAngle(), -90, radius, worldMidX, worldMidY);

                // The "out of view" radius, this represents the "end point" for our projectile, because, it's easier 
                // to calculate
                double outOfViewRadius = Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 2d;
                Point2D outOfViewToPoint = Util.getPointOnCircle(tank.getTurretAngle(), -90, outOfViewRadius, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
                g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                // The projectiles path
                g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(fromPoint, outOfViewToPoint));

                // A line from the barrel to the mouse point
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(fromPoint, toPoint));
            }
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Projectile projectile : projectiles) {
                Point2D current = projectile.getLocation();
                g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(current.getX() - 2, current.getY() - 2, 4, 4));
                // >>> DEBUG
                g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(projectile.getFrom(), projectile.getTo()));
                // << DEBUG
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Util {
        public static Point2D getPointOnCircle(double degress, double offset, double radius) {
            double rads = Math.toRadians(degress + offset); // 0 becomes the top

            // Calculate the outter point of the line
            double xPosy = Math.cos(rads) * radius;
            double yPosy = Math.sin(rads) * radius;

            return new Point2D.Double(xPosy, yPosy);
        }

        public static Point2D getPointOnCircle(double degress, double offset, double radius, double centerX, double centerY) {
            Point2D poc = getPointOnCircle(degress, offset, radius);
            return new Point2D.Double(poc.getX() + centerX, poc.getY() + centerY);
        }
    }

    public class Projectile {
        private Point2D from;
        private Point2D to;

        private Point2D current;

        private long lastUpdate = 0;

        private double deltaX;
        private double deltaY;

        public Projectile(Point2D from, Point2D to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            current = new Point2D.Double(from.getX(), from.getY());

            double deltaX = from.getX() - to.getX();
            double deltaY = from.getY() - to.getY();
            double angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) + Math.toRadians(180);

            this.deltaY = Math.sin(angle) * 100;
            this.deltaX = Math.cos(angle) * 100;
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public Point2D getFrom() {
            return from;
        }

        public Point2D getTo() {
            return to;
        }

        public Point2D getLocation() {
            return current;
        }

        public void tick() {
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate;
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

            double x = current.getX();
            double y = current.getY();

            x += deltaX * (elapsedTime / 1000d);
            y += deltaY * (elapsedTime / 1000d);

            current.setLocation(x, y);
        }

    }

    public class Tank {
        private BufferedImage body;
        private BufferedImage turret;

        private int x;
        private int y;

        private double bodyAngle = 0;
        private double turretAngle = 0;

        private int width;
        private int height;

        private int midX;
        private int midY;

        public Tank() throws IOException {
            body = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/TankBody.png"));
            turret = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/TankTurret.png"));

            width = body.getWidth();
            height = body.getHeight();

            midX = width / 2;
            midY = height / 2;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double getBodyAngle() {
            return bodyAngle;
        }

        public double getTurretAngle() {
            return turretAngle;
        }

        public void setBodyAngle(double bodyAngle) {
            this.bodyAngle = bodyAngle;
        }

        public void setTurretAngle(double turretAngle) {
            this.turretAngle = turretAngle;
        }

        // This represents the "unrotated" width
        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        // This represents the "unrotated" height
        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        protected int getMidX() {
            return midX;
        }

        protected int getMidY() {
            return midY;
        }

        protected BufferedImage getBody() {
            return body;
        }

        protected BufferedImage getTurret() {
            return turret;
        }

        public Point2D getBusinessEndOfBarrel() {
            // I've deliberatly set up the images to be the same size, so this
            // can be made easier.  If your turren is a different size/position
            // then you will need calculate this yourself

            // Also, we're calculating this in "world" space
            int centerX = getX();
            int centerY = getY();
            return Util.getPointOnCircle(getTurretAngle(), -90, Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2, centerX, centerY);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D master, ImageObserver observer) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) master.create();
            g2d.translate(getX() - getMidX(), getY() - getMidY());

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            Graphics2D bodyG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            bodyG.rotate(Math.toRadians(getBodyAngle()), getMidX(), getMidY());
            // >>> Debug
            bodyG.setColor(Color.ORANGE.darker());
            bodyG.drawRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
            // <<< Debug
            bodyG.drawImage(getBody(), 0, 0, observer);
            bodyG.dispose();

            Graphics2D turrtG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            turrtG.rotate(Math.toRadians(getTurretAngle()), getMidX(), getMidY());
            // >>> Debug
            turrtG.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
            // I mesured the turrent size in a image editor
            // The acutal image size is the same as the body
            // in order to make the workflow simpler
            turrtG.drawRect((getWidth() - 20) / 2, 0, 20, 44);
            // <<< Debug
            turrtG.drawImage(getTurret(), 0, 0, observer);
            turrtG.dispose();

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```