# How to make diagonal movement obey Pythagoras?

Tags: java

I've just started programming and I'm having a bit of an issue with character movement. My issue is that the characters move in diagonal (it's 2D) to, lets say, the left top corner to the bottom right corner in the same time they move only from the left top to the right top. How do I make it respect the Pythagoras' theorem?

```java
public class Player extends Rectangle{
    
    public double spd = 1; //1 is the minimum
    public boolean right, up, down, left;
    
    public Player(int x, int y) {
        super(x,y,32,32);
        
    }

    public void tick() {
        if(right) {
            x += spd;
        }else if(left) {
            x -= spd;
        }else if (down) {
            y += spd;
        }else if(up) {
            y -= spd;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "respect Pythagoras theorem"?

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411743/how-to-move-paint-graphics-along-slope/72412859#72412859)

Comment: Do you want the character to be able to move at any angle?  Or only the angle of the line from the top left to bottom right of the window?

Answer (score 3):

Let us add a few more directions:

```
private double angle = 0; // 0 = left-to-right, Math.PI/2 = up, ...
public void tick() {
   x += Math.cos(angle) * spd;
   y += Math.sin(angle) * spd;
}
```

To preserve movement speed, you need to start using [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) (cosine and sine) to ensure that total speed is always the same. For a speed of 1, you can easily check that diagonal movement with

```
   x += 0.7f; // ~ 1/sqrt(2) = sin(45 degrees) = sin(pi/4)
   y += 0.7f;
```

is approximately correct, and "looks" about the same speed as horizontal or vertical movement. Quoting Pythagoras,

```
  a^2 + b^2 = h^2                 // pythagoras
  dx*dx + dy*dy = spd*spd         // for this specific instance
  1/2 + 1/2 = 1                   // plugging in our values, diagonal movement
  1 + 0 = 1                       // horizontal movement
  cos(angle)^2 + sin(angle)^2 = 1 // definition of sine and cosine
```

Of course, for this to work, `x` and `y` should be either `double` or `float` - otherwise you will not be able to add fractional amounts.